# Please Help! Need to dramatically increase the efficiency in a python for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

hope anyone can help me with this as I don't know any better.
I built this for loop where I need to link stock movements with the order that triggered each of them.
The data sets both for orders and stock are huge (>2.000.000 rows) and I built this for loop which is working fine, but very slowly: it would take 74 days to complete by my math.
I need you guys and your magician eyes to take a look at it and tell me what I could be doing to increase this loop's efficiency, as I'm sure I'm doing a lot of rookie mistakes.

**EDIT:** Stack Overflow asked me to focus the question, sorry guys. I think my issue here is that I'm using a lot of pd.DataFrames in the loop because it was the only way I found to make it work with the datetime operations I'm using and extracting the lines to the result dataframe "inserts".
I think it could get better if I used arrays instead, I just don't know how to frame it or even make it work because of all the datatype errors I get.
Please take a look at the Dataframe operations in the code and tell me if you spot any grotesque mistake that is making this run so slow.

```
    for index, row in FOLredux.iterrows():

    # leave stockmov update to another processing step, so this can go faster

    newrow = []
    rollingDF = []

    if row['HadNoStock'] == 'Yes':

        stepdate = row['CheckStockDate']

    else:

        stepdate = row['DecidePackagingDate']


    insertedMovList = inserts['MovementDate'][(inserts['SiteID'] == row['SiteId']) & (inserts['ProductID'] == row['ProductId'])
                                        & (inserts['SizeValue'] == row['SizeValue'])]


    rollingDF = pd.DataFrame({'MovementDate':[StockMov['MovementDate'][(StockMov['siteid'] == row['SiteId']) & (StockMov['ProductID'] == row['ProductId'])
                                        & (StockMov['SizeValue'] == row['SizeValue']) & (StockMov['Delta'] == row['QtySold']*-1) 
                                        ]][0]})

    rollingDF['TotalTime'] = (stepdate - rollingDF['MovementDate']).dt.total_seconds()


    stockdate = pd.DataFrame({'MovementDate': [rollingDF['MovementDate'][(rollingDF['TotalTime'] >= -10)  & (rollingDF['TotalTime'] <= 10)]][0]})

    if len(stockdate) != 0:

        stockdate = stockdate['MovementDate'][~stockdate['MovementDate'].isin(insertedMovList)]



    if len(stockdate) == 0:

        #use creation date

        stepdate = row['BoutiqueOrderDate']

        insertedMovList = inserts['MovementDate'][(inserts['SiteID'] == row['SiteId']) & (inserts['ProductID'] == row['ProductId'])
                                        & (inserts['SizeValue'] == row['SizeValue'])]


        rollingDF = pd.DataFrame({'MovementDate':[StockMov['MovementDate'][(StockMov['siteid'] == row['SiteId']) & (StockMov['ProductID'] == row['ProductId'])
                                        & (StockMov['SizeValue'] == row['SizeValue']) & (StockMov['Delta'] == row['QtySold']*-1) 
                                        ]][0]})

        rollingDF['TotalTime'] = (rollingDF['MovementDate'] - stepdate).dt.total_seconds()/60

        stockdate = pd.DataFrame({'MovementDate': [rollingDF['MovementDate'][(rollingDF['TotalTime'] >= 0)  & (rollingDF['TotalTime'] <= 60)]][0]})

        if len(stockdate) != 0:

            stockdate = stockdate['MovementDate'][~stockdate['MovementDate'].isin(insertedMovList)]


            if len(stockdate) != 0:

                stockdate = min(stockdate)

                orderid = row['OrderCodeId']

                values = [orderid, stockdate, row['SiteId'], row['ProductId'], row['SizeValue'], 1, 0]

                zipped = zip(columns, values)

                data = dict(zipped)

                newrow.append(data)

                inserts = inserts.append(newrow, True)

    else:

        stockdate = min(stockdate)

        orderid = row['OrderCodeId']

        values = [orderid, stockdate, row['SiteId'], row['ProductId'], row['SizeValue'], 0, 0]

        zipped = zip(columns, values)

        data = dict(zipped)

        newrow.append(data)

        inserts = inserts.append(newrow, True)
```

Essentially, this is linking the order to the stock movement based on how close the dates are, product information and uses the help of an aux dataframe (inserts) to not repeat the link to a previously used stock log.
PLEASE HELP :))))

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am relatively new to Python, so don't expect my question to be the highest in quality.

I don't see a loop function at the bottom. You could put the code under a def code(): such as: **def main():** and then at the bottom, add: **main().**

```
def main():
    # Code goes here
main()
```

The **main()** at the bottom runs the code under **def main():** again. If you are importing libraries, make sure it is at the top of the code, not under **def main():**.